# Jquery ui tabs with knockout using mvc 3 how to implement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am developing a web app using asp.net mvc 3. I have a main layout page which contains jquery ui tabs.

I am using knockout.js binding tool. My issue is from my tabs how can I go the relevant controller to return the view. Example is I click on tasks project so in the container for the view it should show the tasks page as rendered by the tasks controller

Any help would be good

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to us RenderPartial.  Then you can either bind each tab via knockout, or bind the whole lot of them.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("TabOne", Model);%>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("TabTwo", Model);%>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("TabThree", Model);%>
</div>
```

This assumes that the html content doesn't vary based off of the data, or at least not so much that knockout can't take care of it.  If your html varies a lot you can use a routing system like Crossroads.js (http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/) and fetch the data for the div using ajax.

Comment: Cheers for that. My tabs will bring back different pages with different data e.g,. project tab will show project, contact tab will show list of contacts etc..