# Tab in MVC application using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foundation

In my application i have tab at the top of the page which should each render a new page.

The tabs are defined in the Layouts file as this will be part of the standard view.

Now i have created different views for each of the options e.g. project is one of the tabs.

So when i click the tab option how will it render the body based on the tab i have selected?

I have used the Foundation layout tabs but will need jquery hooking into it to launch an event.

Any examples or replies would be great

Comment: Possible duplicate of your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654294/jquery-ui-tabs-with-knockout-using-mvc-3-how-to-implement

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Edit 1:

```
<div id="tabs"> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li> 
    </ul> 

    <div id="projects"> 
        <% Html.RenderAction("Projects", "Home"); %> 
    </div> 

    <div id="tab-2"> 
        <% Html.RenderAction("TabTwo", "Home"); %> 
    </div> 

    <div id="tab-3"> 
        <% Html.RenderAction("TabThree", "Home"); %> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Decorate your tabs action method with `[ChildActionOnly]` if you want methods to work using child view only.

Comment: The OP already has a technology for tabs and looking at previous posts it is Jquery UI Tabs. The OP stated the tabs are on the layout page. The question, as far as I can gather, is on how to load a full view  (not partial view) when clicking on one of the tabs. The question is not about what technology to use.

Comment: I have updated answer accordingly. See Edit 1. Let see if OP really cares.